# How to know when a quintic is solvable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So according to Abel-Ruffini Theorem, it states that there is no algebraic solution, in the form of radicals, to general polynomials of degree $5$ or higher.

But I'm wondering if there is a way to decide whether a polynomial, such as $$x^5+14x^4+12x^3+9x+2=0$$
has roots that can be expressed in radicals or not just by having a glance at the polynomial.

Comment: You could compute its Galois Group to check *if* you can solve it in radicals.

Comment: @Ed_4434 What's a "Galois Group"? I have *some* knowledge in group theory, but I have never heard the term Galois Group. Is it something you commonly learn in school?

Comment: Try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group).  Of course that requires a lot more than a glance.  A CAS would be handy.

Comment: Modulo $3$ it has a factor of degree $3$, and modulo $7$ it is irreducible, so its Galois group contains $A_5$, hence it is not solvable. That's a bit more than a glance though, and requires some knowledge of group theory.

Comment: @Frank It's a more or less advanced undergraduate/graduate object which in some sense looks at the solvability of a polynomial.

Comment: +1 for the good question. Unfortunately, as commenters tell you, there is no way to answer it given your level of mathematical knowledge.

Comment: A course on Galois Theory tends to lead you through the computation of galois groups and related concepts. The "punchline" of the course is usually a proof of Abel-Ruffini which is definitely something to aim for if you're interested in algebra.

Comment: Always check the rational roots theorem first?

Comment: @Simple Art Yes. But none of the roots work. The problem with the rational roots theorem is if the root is... well, irrational. Like $\sqrt2$. So just the roots from the rational root theorem isn't going to decide whether the polynomial can be solved.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Oh.. Then what *do* I have to learn to be able to decide whether or not a polynomial can be solvable? I see alot of stuff about groups, so I'm gonna guess group theory... is that it?

Comment: @Frank Well, it doesn't hurt to check the rational roots theorem.  And I'm not too familiar with the stuff, but you should learn Galois theory, as mentioned, to determine if it is factorable.

Comment: As @Ed_4434 comments, you'll need to get as far in abstract algebra as Galois theory. That's at least one course, probably two. Whether you can do it by reading depends on how firm your "some knowledge of group theory" is, and your personality and determination. If you want to read, consider asking a separate question and making clear your current state of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have commented, to know when a quintic (or higher) is solvable in radicals requires Galois theory. However, there is a rather simple aspect when it is ***not*** solvable that is easily understood and can be used as a litmus test.

***Theorem***: *An irreducible equation of prime degree $p>2$ that is solvable in radicals has either $1$ or $p$ real roots.*

(Irreducible, simply put, means it has no rational roots.) By sheer coincidence, the irreducible quintic you chose has $3$ real roots so, by looking at its graph, you can indeed tell at a glance that this is ***not*** solvable in radicals. Going higher, if an irreducible septic has $3$ or $5$ real roots, then you automatically know it is not solvable. And so on.

**P.S.** And before you ask, it does not work the other direction: if it has $1$ or $p$ real roots, it does ***not*** imply it is solvable in radicals. It is a necessary but not sufficient condition.

Comment: I have studied Galois theory, but I have never come across that theorem! How is it proved?

Comment: @Unit: I believe Dummit mentions it briefly in his paper on quintics, but I know it was established before him. How to prove it, I leave to those more capable than I.  :)